# Nokia 520 hibernate

Tags: lumia

I am facing a strange issue with my Nokia Lumia 520 mobile. It just seem to go to hibernation after about 5 minutes.

A couple of times it came alive with a tap on the power switch. But now it needs more pressing and prompting which is irritating.I am guessing there has to be a setting to prevent this.

I see a screen lockout option under settings. But it could be set only to maximum of 5 minutes. 
Is it an issue with my phone alone or something that can be rectified. Please guide.

Comment: Even when the phone is in 'sleep mode', it should wake instantly when you press the sleep/wake/power button. Have you restarted the phone, does it continue? are there any updates for the phone?

Comment: I have updated the phone software. Also restarted the phone. For once or twice it woke up from 'sleep mode' immediately on pressing the power button. Then back to old ways. Need lot of cajoling-->  read keep pressing the power button for extended period of time to start up. Sometimes i press it along with volume button because i am not sure what works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got things figured out.
The first thing is the Nokia Lumia will lock the screen after a period of time set in settings-->lock screen-->Screen times out after x minutes.
Now the maximum that can be set here is 5 minutes. Supposedly it is a feature to protect the battery and we have to live with it. So the screen appears blank after this time.

Now like Neil Turner pointed out it should have been out of 'sleep' the moment we pressed the power on button. The problem in this case was the protecting case of the Nokia Lumia. Most of these back covers do not fit in exactly and even a slight gap causes this behavior. It was even more surprising because i bought a cover specifically made for this model. When i removed the back cover what i needed was just a gentle touch on the power/lock button to make it active. And like HalaBi pointed out it can be due to the power button itself or can be misunderstood as such an issue due to the back cover.

Comment: Consider mark your answer as "the answer" for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, it turned out to be a hardware issue with the lock button in 520. The repair shop it is a common problem.

Once the button is fixed everything was fine. Just get it fixed.

Comment: I took it to a local shop. They told me to try software update. But it was not an authorized Nokia center and software update did not fix the issue, so will try taking to one and see if it is an hardware issue.